Formio dynamic title inside Data Grid
I am working on a data grid where I need to add enumerated titles to each row. The titles should update dynamically whenever rows are added or deleted. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:
For example:
1. Row
2. Row
3. Row
< Add more row >

If I delete the 2nd row, the enumeration should update automatically to:
1. Row
2. Row (formerly 3rd Row)
< Add more row >


Requirements:
The enumeration should reflect the correct row numbers at all times.
When a row is deleted, the subsequent rows should update their titles accordingly.
New rows should be added with the next sequential number.
I was trying to achive this with the advanced logic feaure but no luck at the moment.
